# Cannot echo php value inside javascript

Tags: javascript, php, echo

```
var countDownDate = new Date("<?php echo file_get_contents('wipetime.txt');?>").getTime();
```

I'm trying to make a countdown timer. The file "wipetime.txt" changes every few days so I'm trying to make it so I can grab the file when the page loads and countdown to that date.

The problem is that if I echo that php value somewhere on the page, it works. It displays the file contents. However, if I were to echo it inside countDownDate or even an alert, I get nothing. No error, just completely nothing.

I can't see anything wrong at all.

Edit: Heres the entire thing in case you wanna know

```
<!--Whitelist timer-->
<script>
var countDownDate = new Date("<?php echo file_get_contents('wipetime.txt');?>").getTime();
var x = setInterval(function() {
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  var distance = countDownDate - now;
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
  document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Whitelist expires in " + days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show the generated html? Show us what appears under page-source/view-source. Also is this a `.js` file?

Comment: And I'm sorry if the info i've given is kind of vague. I don't really know what else to say, this is really basic and /should/ work, but for some reason I just get nothing. Am I overlooking something stupid?

Comment: The problem is that we can't tell what is the generated code on the page. We can't tell if you are doing this in a php file or a js file.

Comment: var countDownDate = new Date("Oct 05, 2018 06:39:03
").getTime();

Thats what chrome console is saying it outputted. The entire page is in php but the specific javascript is at the end of the page

Comment: If I paste Oct 05, 2018 06:39:03 into the quotes rather than the php, it works, but that means I can't get the date dynamically, which is what I'm trying to do. If I use the script I posted above, it doesn't display anything at all

Comment: Do a `console.log(countDownDate);` after setting it. I have the impression that the text file contains a special charater that is invalidating the time.

Comment: Hey, that did it my man! I should have realized this earlier, but my file had an extra blank line in it that was throwing everything off. I didn't see that until you told me to check the log. Appreciate it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a possibility that the file `wipetime.txt` contains some special characters (maybe a carriage return). Two things you can do:

1. Manually check the file for any artifacts and remove them.
2. You should trim the content.

The code:

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents('wipetime.txt');
$timeStr = trim($content); // should remove trailing characters like new lines. 
?>

var countDownDate = new Date("<?php echo $timeStr;?>").getTime();
```

Comment: I'm generating wipetime.txt with the command line in linux and for some reason its outputting an extra line, so this answer works perfectly.

Comment: They're going to be out of luck if the value contains a `"` for some reason. `json_encode()` is a handy way to escape things for insertion into JavaScript.